# AWS codecommit not working with git-remote-codecommit

Tags: aws-codecommit

I am working on aws cloud and using codecommit service. I want to set up git-remote-codecommit tool on my ubuntu OS. but it give me error.
Here I was trying to follow following document.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-git-remote-codecommit.html as federated user.

[image]

I added version information about OS and other required tools.
But after doing all this when try to execute

```
git clone codecommit: command it throws fatal error.
```

Can someone help me, what is root cause for this and how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Based on the screenshot, it seems it is missing the codecommit helper. Could you check that you installed it using this command in the doc page `pip install git-remote-codecommit` ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AWS Codecommit, it is a great service but has its quirks.

- First question for you is have you configured your IAM role properly to have STS Assume role access?  If you have not done that this role will not work with the federation. I would need to see a sample of your IAM role before I can help you debug the issue.

Additionally i am providing this link which walks you through the setup for federated roles:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-federated-identities-with-aws-codecommit/